# Continous Looping with Nested Loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop

an example of the code I am trying to execute is as follows:

```
puts 'Please choose "A" or "B"?'
STDOUT.flush
@answer = gets.chomp.upcase
while @answer != "A" || "B"
    puts 'Invalid answer, choose "A" or B"'
    STDOUT.flush
    @answer = gets.chomp.upcase

end
```

How can I get this to stop looping once A or B is entered. If I remove the While loop I can get @answer to become A or B but once I add that it continually loops no matter what I type in.

Comment: You need `while @answer != "A" && @answer != "B"`.  Operator precedence matters here.

Comment: accept this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184727/check-for-similar-values-of-symbols-within-an-array if it helps you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your WHILE condition is not good, you can't just say A || B, maybe repeat the condition? Maybe like this?

```
while @answer != "A" || @answer != "B"
```

Hope it helps. :)

(edit: maybe even use `AND (&&)` instead of `OR (||)` ?)

Comment: Should be `&&` not `||`.

Comment: Yup, thought of that too after I posted the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The below way will also work :

```
unless ["A","B"].include? @answer
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I tried Arup's answer and it works, but the `while` expression is still not really correct. It behaves as a `while true` which is why the `break` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
@answer = nil 
until @answer == 'A' || @answer == 'B' do
  @answer = gets.chomp
end
```